# Server returned bad request when trying to install Unity

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, unity-container, nuget

I'm trying to use NuGet to install Unity. I first had an error when trying to search for Unity:

> The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https
>   scheme.

After googling, apparently I needed the same NuGet link but HTTP instead of HTTPS. After adding the new NuGet HTTP package source, I can now search for (and find) Unity:

[image]

However, when I click Install, I get this error:

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'CommonServiceLocator (≥ 1.0)'. The
>   remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

[image]

I'm not sure how to resolve this. Does anyone know?

Comment: I believe so. We've had issues where we couldn't use the online gallery at all (unless we were working from home) until recently (we altered our devenv.exe.config to add a defaultProxy node).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Package Manager Console?

```
Install-Package CommonServiceLocator
```

Then

```
Install-Package Unity
```

Comment: +1 for the tip. I tried that but I got this: `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` Perhaps my environment is hosed as my VS 2012 update hung as well. Maybe I'll uninstall/reinstall VS 2012.

Comment: Can you check which request is failing using fiddler and then may be trying reaching the same url thru browser.